# Google Analytics "Acquisition Channels: Bookings" vs. "Attribution Last Click conversions"

Tags: google, google-analytics, conversions

I'm looking looking into attribution model analysis and assumed our standard booking numbers would match last click but the numbers do not match up.

I would have assumed GA counts transactions on a last click level so I'm unsure as to why in the attribution model last click does not match.

Answer (score 1):

Last-click is the default in Model Comparison Tool, but Last non-direct click is the default in Analytics.